# Some files won't transfer to an external hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When backing up an external hard drive on Windows 10 some files won’t copy and paste to another hard drive.

The contents of the drive I want to copy are the following folders:

- inspiration (62.4GB)
- old stuff (7.9GB)
- music (17.5GB)
- my_computer (1.78GB)
- school backup (638MB)
- working_files (19.7GB)

I was able to transfer some with file copy: the “school backup,” “my_computer,” and “music.”

At first I thought the reason some weren’t copying over was because of the file size but the music folder with 17.5GB transferred ok. Meanwhile the old stuff folder won't copy.

I also tried copying subfolders from the old stuff folder and none of those will copy either. I checked the permissions on the blocked folder and all of the permissions are allowed.

What would cause some folders to copy and paste to another location and stop others?

Comment: What type of formatting are you using? Right click on the drive in my computer, go to properties and see what "File System" is.

Comment: The drive the folder is in uses: NTFS
The drive I am transferring to: NTFS

Comment: I tried going further to some subfolders and found some of the files have been corrupted. I think that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A corrupted subfolder within the hard drive caused it to be unable to transfer to another location. To find the corrupted files open the folder, it will give the error "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable."